# Why my Xamarin Parse project for Android do not compile?

Tags: xamarin, parse-platform, nuget

When i try to compile my Xamarin project in an android device this error pops up. Tried adding the NuGet Parse package in the Andoid project but it still does not work.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUtCM.png)

Comment: do NOT post errors as images

Comment: Try updating the Parse package and check for any dependencies.

Comment: don't put part of the question as a link to another site please.